# How to keep my navigation bar stick to the top?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my nagivation bar to stick to the top of the page but can't for some reason. I tried looking up and I tried a few things but they didn't work.

```
     body {
       background-color:black;
     }
     ul {
       list-style-type: none;
       margin: -8;
       padding-bottom: 0px;
       padding-top: 0px;
       overflow:hidden;
       background-color:rgb(235,0,0);
       margin-top: 5px;
       font-family: ariel;
     }
    li {
      padding-left: 35%;
    }
    li a {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 25px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-right: 25px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    li a:link {
      color:white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:visited {
      color:purple;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover {
      background-color:rgb(200,0,0);
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: auto;
    }
    li a:active {
      color:rgb(100,100,100);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

As you can see I used `ul`, `li` and `a` tags to make the nav bar and to get it in a horizontal form I use `float: left`
Thanks!

Comment: what are you using, bootstrap ?? and please add your`HTML`  code

Comment: Please show us the HTML markup.

Comment: Please add your HTML code. A quick fix, you can try position: fixed; for sticky nav

Answer (score 0):

You can us: "position:fixed" on your navigation.

To learn more about positions https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

**Example:**

```
  ul {
     position:fixed;
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: -8;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     padding-top: 0px;
     overflow:hidden;
     width:100%;
     background-color:rgb(235,0,0);
     margin-top: 5px;
     font-family: ariel;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/twsyu9mc/1/

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help. Your fiddle made it work! is there a way to make it so that the bar will first go to the top of the page as i scroll down and then stick on the top of the page when theres no more place to go up as right now floating in the middle?

Comment: Hi, good that my answer works. Can you please upvote my answer, thanks. For your other question I think you mean something like this: https://codepen.io/renduh/pen/oBBGbK

Comment: Hi! Thanks again for the code. I upvoted your comment althought my reputation is low so i doubt it helped.

Answer (score 0):

position:fixed;
use this in your ul

Comment: i tried that but then my nav bar from a vertical bar turns to a horizontal one at the left side of the screen